# MacBook Air (Early 2015) Network Driver for Linux

Tags: network, driver, dual-boot

I got an unexpected question when installing a Debian Based Linux on my Late 2015 MacBook Air:

```
Detect network hardware

No Ethernet card was detected. If you know the name of the driver
needed by your Ethernet cars, you can select it from the list.
```

The list is huge.

[image]

Some of the notable names are:

- rtl8723ae: Realtek 8723e 802.11ax PCI wireless
- b43legacy: Broadcom 4400 10/100 PCI Ethernet
- adm8211: Driver for IEEE 802.11b wireless cards based on ADMtek ADM8211

I would restart and try to find information in it, but the installation was failing before ( tried more than 10 times), and it is working now. I don't wanna take any chances.

This is the only information I found in Apple's website :

> Wireless: 802.11ac Wi-Fi wireless networking; IEEE 802.11a/b/g/n
>   compatible

What is the right driver? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a late 2015 MacBook Air model. I'm assuming you have the early 2015 model.

In that case your computer has a Broadcom BCM4360 chipset for WiFi.

The driver you would need in debian is the "wl" driver. You will probably need to install the broadcom-sta-dkms package manually and then load the wl driver.

The driver is non-free/binary-only so probably not listed during installation.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue, although Broadcomm BCM4360 is unavailable. And realtek drivers failed to initialize.